# Convert one table into two new tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, export

I am trying to move data from one table into two new tables, but I am unsure how I can do this in the best and most foolproof way.

I have about 2000 rows in newsletter_users that looks like this:

```
userid company email memberofgroup
```

where

```
memberofgroup
```

is an integer that refers to newsletter_mailgroups. This is not the best way if a user wants to be a member of different groups. Then there will be x rows with the same email. 2000 users x 3 or 4 different groups (what did I think of??) Therefore I have made two new tables

newsletter_members that look like this

```
userid email company
```

and another table newsletter_member_of_group that look like this:

```
field_member_uid field_user_id field_memberofgroup
```

where

```
field_user_id
```

will contain a users id from newsletter_members and

```
field_memberofgroup
```

will contain the emailgroup id. f.x.

```
field_user_id  field_memberofgroup 
    2                 6
    2                 4
    2                 8
    3                 1
    5                 6
```

How can I export and then import them in the best way so that emails will not duplicate in newsletter_members? - I might need to do a manual check to see which users a members of more than one mailgroup.

Mailgroups table:

```
1   Forhandlere 
2   Arkitekter og byggerÃ¥dgivere   
3   Typehusfabrikanter  
4   ByggeentreprenÃ¸rer 
5   Murermestre 
6   TÃ¸mrermestre   
7   TagdÃ¦kkere 
8   Boligforeninger/Ejendomsselskaber   
9   Bygge-interesserede 
10  Tyske modtagere 
11  Landskabsarkitekter 
12  Norske arkitekter   
13  Svenske arkitekter  
14  Norske forhandlere  
15  Svenske forhandlere 
16  Brancherelaterede   
17  Svenske ansatte 
18  Norske ansatte  
19  Beijer Sverige
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in few steps:

- **Craete** table `newsletter_member_of_group`.

Script:

```
 CREATE TABLE newsletter_member_of_group(
  field_member_uid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  field_user_id INT,
  field_memberofgroup INT
);
```

Note that field_member_uid is AUTO_INCREMENT, it will help us to insert ID values.

- **Copy** data from `newsletter_users` to `newsletter_member_of_group`.

Script:

```
INSERT INTO newsletter_member_of_group
  SELECT NULL, userid, memberofgroup FROM newsletter_users;
```

- **Create** `newsletter_members` table. We have two variants: create new table and copy data, or rename `newsletter_users` to `newsletter_members` and drop `memberofgroup` field. I choose second variant.

Script:

```
ALTER TABLE newsletter_users RENAME TO newsletter_members;
ALTER TABLE newsletter_members DROP COLUMN memberofgroup;
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't think about just alter the existing table! This way I will get it exactly as it is! I am the resetting the ids and import those into the new memberofgroup table! Thank you!